# How unique are the first 8-12 characters of SHA256 hashes?

Tags: url, hash, sha256, hash-collision

Take this hash for example:

```
ba7816bf 8f01cfea 414140de 5dae2223 b00361a3 96177a9c b410ff61 f20015ad
```

It's too long for my purposes so I intend to use a small chunk from it, such as:

```
ba7816bf8f01
ba7816bf
```

Or similar. My intended use case:

- Video gallery on a website, represented by thumbnails. They are in random order.
- They play in the lightbox. They don't have a unique ID, only their URL is unique.
- While the lightbox is open I add something to the end of the page URL with [JS History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

> //example.com/video-gallery/**lightbox/ba7816bf8f01**

- The suffix needs to be short and simple, definitely not a URL.
- People share the URL.
- The server can make sense of the lightbox/ba7816bf8f01 in relation to /video-gallery.
- Visiting the URL, the lightbox needs to find which video the suffix belongs to and play it.

I thought I'd SHA256 the URL of the video, use the first few characters as an ad-hoc ID. **How many characters should I use** from the generated hash, to considerably reduce the chance of collision?

I got the idea from [URLs and Hashing by Google](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/urls-hashing).

Comment: you could use a function that produces a shorter hash like md5... or should be fine just truncating your sha256. You increase the chance of collision from almost impossible to slightly less almost impossible.

Comment: maybe also consider base64 encoding to increase the number of bits encoded in your id. I see this done all the time- look at image links on imgur

Comment: I've thought about that. Why is `base_convert("ba7816bf8f01", 16, 36);`
shorter (when it uses less possible characters) than `base64_encode("ba7816bf8f01");`?

Comment: that is the string representation of those bytes in hex. A hex character is 4 bits but the string representation of that character is 16 bits. You need to base64 encode the bytes, not the string representing those bytes

Comment: well... depends on what you are using. In java char is 16 bits, in C its 8, but in any case its more than the underlying bytes you are representing.

Comment: Consider base58 encoding instead of base64. It has a number advantages when generating human-readable identifiers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [birthday attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack#Mathematics) has a table with the number of entries you need to produce a certain chance of collision with a certain number of bits as a random identifier. If you want to have a one in a million chance of a collision and expect to store a million documents, for example, you’ll need fewer than 64 bits (16 hex characters).

[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a good way to fit more bits into the same length of string compared to hex, too, taking 1⅓ characters per byte instead of 2.

Comment: Would I Base64 the hash or the source URL?

Comment: @Firsh: The hash. In PHP, that looks like `base64_encode(hash('sha256', $input, true))` – note the `true` to give raw instead of hex-encoded hash output.